# How to match an optional subpattern in the middle or end of an url depending on the existence of a filename and extension

Tags: php, regex, url, slug

I am trying to preg_match a url consisting of a category slug, an optional subcategory slug and an option item slug.

It works in all cases, except for the 4th case.

```
$urls[0] = '/main_cat_slug';
$urls[1] = '/main_cat_slug/';
$urls[2] = '/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug';
$urls[3] = '/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/';
$urls[4] = '/main_cat_slug/item.html';
$urls[5] = '/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/item.html';

$regexp   = array();
$regexp[] = '/(?:(?<category>[\w]+)/?)';    // Find the main category (is always available)
$regexp[] = '(?:(?<subcategory>[\w]+)/?)?'; // Find an optional sub-category, is not always available
$regexp[] = '(?:(?<item>[\w]+)\.html)?';    // Find an optional item, is not always available (don't catch the extension)
$regexp   = implode('', $regexp);

foreach($urls as $index=>$url) {
preg_match("#{$regexp}#i", $url, $matches);
echo '<pre><h1>', $index, '</h1>';
echo $url, '<br />';
echo '<br />';
print_r($matches);
}
```

In the 4-th case, the category will be found, but the item is empty and the subcategory gets the value op "item".

Could someone help me out, so that the 4-th case will only get a category and an item?

This is the output for above code:

```
0
/main_cat_slug

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
)

1
/main_cat_slug/

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug/
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
)

2
/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
    [subcategory] => sub_cat_slug
    [2] => sub_cat_slug
)

3
/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
    [subcategory] => sub_cat_slug
    [2] => sub_cat_slug
)

4
/main_cat_slug/item.html

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug/item
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
    [subcategory] => item
    [2] => item
)

5
/main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/item.html

Array
(
    [0] => /main_cat_slug/sub_cat_slug/item.html
    [category] => main_cat_slug
    [1] => main_cat_slug
    [subcategory] => sub_cat_slug
    [2] => sub_cat_slug
    [item] => item
    [3] => item
)
```

Kind regards!
Patrick

Comment: Can you have more than one subcat, example `/main_cat/subcat1/subcat2` ?

Comment: And have your files always the `.html` extension?

Comment: For now we only have 1 subcategory max.
Files always have the .html extension.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will pickout the three types of data, using the following rules:

1. The `/` is always the first character in the string
2. The Main_Cat is always first, it follows the first `/` and continues until the next `/`
3. If the first string ends in `.html/` then this is a Main_Cat
4. if the first string ends in `.html` followed by the end of the string, then this is an item
5. The Sub_Cat is always second, it follows the second `/` and continues until the next `/`
6. If the second string ends in `.html/` then this is a Sub_Cat
7. if the second string ends in `.html` followed by the end of the string, then this is an item
8. The Item type always has an `.html` suffix
9. There will never be a `/` after the Item
10. the Item type will always be the last field

`^\/(?:(?<Main_Cat>(?![^\/\r\n]*\.html\s*$)[^\/\r\n]*)\/)?(?:(?<Sub_Cat>(?![^\/\r\n]*\.html\s*$)[^\/\r\n]*)\/)?(?:(?<Item>[^\/\r\n]*?)(?:\.html|$))?`

[image]

If you're using this expression against individual strings then you can remove the new line characters `\r\n`. The resulting expression would look like: `^\/(?<Main_Cat>[^\/]*)(?:(?:\/(?![^\/]*\.html)(?<Sub_Cat>[^\/]*))?(?:\/(?<Item>[^\/]*)\.html)?)?.*?$` follows the same rules above. Note the end of line `$` forces the test to match your entire string

## PHP Code Example:

Source String

```
/category0.html/subcat/item.html
/item1.html
/category2.html/subcat2.html/item2.html
/category3.html/subcat3.html/
/category4.html/item4.html
/main_cat_slug5.html/
/main_cat_slug6/item6
/main_cat_slug7/sub_cat_slug7.html/
/main_cat_slug8/item8.html
/main_cat_slug9/sub_cat_slug9/item9.html
```

Code

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^\/(?:(?<Main_Cat>(?![^\/\r\n]*\.html\s*$)[^\/\r\n]*)\/)?(?:(?<Sub_Cat>(?![^\/\r\n]*\.html\s*$)[^\/\r\n]*)\/)?(?:(?<Item>[^\/\r\n]*?)(?:\.html|$))?/imx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

Matches

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /category0.html/subcat/item.html
            [1] => /item1.html
            [2] => /category2.html/subcat2.html/item2.html
            [3] => /category3.html/subcat3.html
            [4] => /category4.html/item4.html
            [5] => /main_cat_slug5.html
            [6] => /main_cat_slug6
            [7] => /main_cat_slug7/sub_cat_slug7.html
            [8] => /main_cat_slug8/item8.html
            [9] => /main_cat_slug9/sub_cat_slug9/item9.html
        )

    [Main_Cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => category0.html
            [1] => 
            [2] => category2.html
            [3] => category3.html
            [4] => category4.html
            [5] => main_cat_slug5.html
            [6] => main_cat_slug6
            [7] => main_cat_slug7
            [8] => main_cat_slug8
            [9] => main_cat_slug9
        )

    [Sub_Cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => subcat
            [1] => 
            [2] => subcat2.html
            [3] => subcat3.html
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => sub_cat_slug7.html
            [8] => 
            [9] => sub_cat_slug9
        )

    [Item] => Array
        (
            [0] => item
            [1] => item1
            [2] => item2
            [3] => 
            [4] => item4
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => item8
            [9] => item9
        )


)
```

Comment: Great. Newline are not necessary to check against and we need the named subpatterns.

One problem with the above sollution: a category can also have a .html extension which is not the case.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement, what do you mean by `a category can also have a .html extension which is not the case.`. Does that mean a category can have `.html`?

Comment: With the mentioned solution, a category can have a .html extension:

/category.html/subcat/item.html

Comment: So with your sample edge case `/category.html/subcat/item.html` I updated the expression to `category.html/` a category whereas given `/notcategory.html` as your input string this will become an item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match('~/(?<main_cat>[^/\s]++/?+)(?<sub_cat>[^/\s]++/?+)?'
         . '(?>(?<filename>\S+?)\.html)?~', $url, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Note that you can access easily to the different parts with the named captures (useful to test if there is a subpattern or not.).